# Simple Statistical Question ... Hard answer?

Tags: probability

I'm struggling to comprehend the most basic of statistical examples.
Here's the setup : someone will perform three throws of a coin in a row.
The face of the coin will return either a 1 or a 0 (heads or tails if you like).
Now there are 8 possible combinations this set of three throws can turn up.

1;1;1
1;1;0
1;0;1
0;1;1
0;0;1
0;1;0
1;0;0
0;0;0

Now you may  gamble which one of the combinations will pop up.

I understand that each of the combinations has 1/8 chance of appearing. 
So choosing  1;1;1   would be as good as choosing  1;0;1 (Or so I would think).

On the other hand however, I see that a series of throws has
6/8 chances to contain a combination of 1 and 0's,
1;1;1 and 0;0;0 together from the rest of the 2/8 chances.

This makes me think that whichever one I choose, it should not be
1;1;1  or  0;0;0

Which of both ideas is the correct one ?

Comment: This cannot be answered unless you specify the conditions of the question/bet. Does sequence matter or not?

Comment: Ah, your question immediately points out my complete lack of knowledge. So I'm going to perform one single set of three throws.
I am going to bet which one of the 8 possibilities will appear. Does any of the 8 combinations has a higher probabillity to appear, or not ? (hope this helps, I have the feeling it's still clumsy ...)

Comment: If you are asked to select one of the eight possibilities, then it is implicit that the sequence matters. In which case all are of equal probability, 1/8. If the sequence does NOT matter, then there are not 8 possibilities to consider, only 4. You are confusing the two situations; thinking about exactly what the bet is will help you understand this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your second reasoning is that if you bet on `1 1 0` and the result is `0 1 0`, it doesn't help that your bet also contained both `0`s and `1`s; it still wasn't the right answer.

It's three times as likely that the result will have a mix of `0`s and `1`s, but there are also three times as many *ways* that it can have a mix of `0`s and `1`s, so it all lines up, and any bet is equally good.

Now, if you could bet on how many `1`s would show up in the result (regardless of order), you'd be better off betting on 1 or 2 than on 0 or 3.

Comment: " It's three times as likely that the result will have a mix of 0s and 1s, but there are also three times as many ways that it can have a mix of 0s and 1s, so it all lines up, and any bet is equally good "  => I believe I got it, that's the bit, in plain words, I was looking for, thank you Dougal !